# Zend 2 Session - destroyed when double click "Enter"

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I got problem with Zend 2 session

When I 'quickly' double click 'Enter' in _POST form ( twice submit form before first respond) session is destroyed. When I submit 'in normal speed' all is OK.

My session configuration is exact copy of this http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html

only difference is

```
'session' => array(
    'config' => array(
        'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
        'options' => array(
            'name' => 'myapp',
            'remember_me_seconds' => 3600, //60 min session
            'use_cookies' => true,
           // 'cookie_httponly' => true, -> not working with Zfc-user subdomain
            'cookie_domain'=>'domain.com',

        ),
    ),
    'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
    'validators' => array(
        'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
        'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
    ),
),
```

In controler I have:

```
const NAMESPACE_REGORG = 'initialized';

protected $_sessionRegContainer;

public function packageAction() {

    //check if user login and redirect
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
       //some staff here
    }

    //save value to session
    $package = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
    $this->_sessionRegContainer = new Container(static::NAMESPACE_REGORG);
    $this->_sessionRegContainer->package = $package;
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(static::ROUTE_LOGIN);
}

public function loginAction() {

    //restore session
    $this->_sessionRegContainer = new Container(static::NAMESPACE_REGORG);

    //create form staff.. if submited by double click session is loosing
    //value of $this->_sessionRegContainer->package
}
```

Page use Doctrine 2 ORM , Zfc-user module for authentication and sub-domain for all Zend 2 related content - main domain.com is static html.

It is worth to mention that when I use simple new Container() session with out all setup from Zend page - session work fine with 'double click' but zfc-user stop to work :(

Any idea  why session is destroyed? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is your form protected with CSRF Element? If so, then it's only normal that the form won't validate. The session shouldn't be destroyed tho.

Comment: Hi Sam, session is destroyed with CSRF and with out CSRF added to form - tested. So problem is somewhere else. As mentioned in orginal post when I use simple new Container() problem disapear.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it by removing

```
$session->start();
$session->rememberMe();
```

from Zend 2 exmple setup -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html

Double click session destroy ended (fixed). 
ps. It look like they already remove rememberMe() from exmple.
Thanks for all help!